# Playing guest clash of clan

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am playing guest coc from beginning when I installed it.

Now I want to convert it to a google id.

Please tell me a method to convert it to a id.

Comment: I am really sorry for wrong tag

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings (second tab in menu opened by clicking Gears in bottom-right corner, just above Shop) and look for Google Play Sign-In ;)